# Compability problems with OpenGeo Suite and already installed GeoServer and others

Tags: installation

Sorry I couldn´t find the answer anywhere else.

I already have GeoServer 2.3.2, Postgres 9.2, OpenLayers 2.13 installed but in addition I need GeoWebCache and probably GeoExt.

Is it wice to download now the whole OpenGeo Suite even if the versions are different or should I try to download GeoWebCache and GeoExt separately?

Thanks for help!

Laura

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that just download and install only the required components. The new releases of GeoServer come with GeoWebCache, so you might not even have to install that.

If you install GeoServer & Postgres from OpenGeo, you could potentially have problem, since they will try to listen to the same Port numbers by default. Additionally, there could be dll problems if you are on windows, and some of the dlls in the two installations are of different versions.